# Pokemon Go, Google Account suddenly not working anymore

Tags: pokemon-go

since yesterday I can't login to my Pokemon Go Account using the Google Login. First I thought server issues again of course but I can do the following:

- Login with a Pokemon trainer account
- Login with my Google account from an emulator

So this issue seems to be related to my phone. I tried to restart and reinstall the app several times but am hitting a wall right now. Anything else I can do to do to purge the app from my phone so I can make a clean reinstall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try deleting pokemon go's chache or app data before reinstalling, or even unlink your google account as well, and link it back in the dialog you get when you click sign in with google without having an account linked already.

If you don't know how to do those, post your phone model in a comment and I'll try to guide you into doing those.

Comment: I had to _purge_ my Google account, re add it, synchronize everything again and Pokemon Go worked again. Thanks a lot